# Devise sign_in resource works even without importing module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

So, I was customizing devise in a custom sign up page which required me to **sign_in** a user after creating the account along with some other operations. After creating the resource I did

```
sign_in resource if resource.active_for_authentication?
```

and it signs in the user. My controller inherits the 
    ApplicationController
and I haven't included any modules like this

```
include Devise::Controllers::SignInOut
```

How did rails know about the

```
sign_in
```

method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Basic answer** - the module Devise::Controllers::Helpers (which includes Devise::Controllers::SignInOut that you discovered) is automatically included in ApplicationController by one of the Devise initializer named "devise.url_helpers". Initializer is included by adding Devise gem, and its content is run during rails Application startup.

**Going deeper**

Devise is a Rails Engine - you can check [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) article for brief review.

> Engines can be considered miniature applications that provide
>   functionality to their host applications. A Rails application is
>   actually just a "supercharged" engine, with the Rails::Application
>   class inheriting a lot of its behavior from Rails::Engine.
>
> ...
>
> Engines are also closely related to *plugins*.

Then, you will find the following call at rails.rb of Devise (this `rails.rb` is required by gem root devise.rb file - see below) [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/4924dd68ae952a427d08c43e7afb2dc8045efbc0/lib/devise/rails.rb#L18):

```
   initializer "devise.url_helpers" do
      Devise.include_helpers(Devise::Controllers)
   end
```

To state, `initializer` here is *not* a method definition, but actual calling a class method with string name parameter and block parameter. It's executed on class load (i.e. as a result of loading a class by `require`). Same time, passed block serves as parameter to this call, and in this particular case is saved to be executed later - see below explanation of initializers.

*Side note* on engines (in fact railtie) **initializer concept**

Initializer is a concept by one of the Rails basic class Railtie. Concept is described [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/railties/lib/rails/railtie.rb):

> Initializers - To add an initialization step from your Railtie to Rails boot process, you just need to create an initializer block:

```
  #   class MyRailtie < Rails::Railtie
  #     initializer "my_railtie.configure_rails_initialization" do
  #       # some initialization behavior
  #     end
  #   end
```

The implementation of initializers logic is part of `Initilizable` [module](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/railties/lib/rails/initializable.rb#L82) which is [included](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/railties/lib/rails/railtie.rb#L117) into Railtie class. Specific initializer class method basically adds passed block to class initializers array [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/railties/lib/rails/initializable.rb#L82):

```
  def initializer(name, opts = {}, &blk)
    ...
    initializers << Initializer.new(name, nil, opts, &blk)
  end
```

It's not executed immediately. It's run by executing `run` method on initializers in specific order by `run_initializers` call, which is also part of `Initializable` [module](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/railties/lib/rails/initializable.rb#L52). This method is available for rails Application with inherits from Engine (which includes `Initializable` module).

```
def run_initializers(group=:default, *args)
  return if instance_variable_defined?(:@ran)
  initializers.tsort_each do |initializer|
    initializer.run(*args) if initializer.belongs_to?(group)
  end
  @ran = true
end
```

This `run_initializers` method is triggered by `initialize!` call (see below a bit later) of the Application.

Side note on **collecting all initializers** by Rails Application.

Meanwhile, `initializers` here is an overloaded [method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/railties/lib/rails/application.rb#L358) in Application class:

```
def initializers #:nodoc:
  Bootstrap.initializers_for(self) +
  railties_initializers(super) +
  Finisher.initializers_for(self)
end
```

This method will load all initializers of the application for further ordering and running.
Inside, `railties_initializers` will call `ordered_railties`, which will use `railties` getter of Engine class (which Application is inherited from). This getter is the [following](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb#L481)

```
def railties
  @railties ||= Railties.new
end
```

`Railties` (plural) service class is different from `Railtie`. It actually just collects all [railties](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/railties/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb) by looking at all subclasses of both Engine and Railtie classes.

```
 def initialize
    @_all ||= ::Rails::Railtie.subclasses.map(&:instance) +
      ::Rails::Engine.subclasses.map(&:instance)
  end
```

Finally, `subclasses` is a method from extension of Ruby base Class, which Rails [extend](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/89e2f7e722e06f900bdb1c14db33073c90d7cdea/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/subclasses.rb) for its convenience

```
  def subclasses
    subclasses, chain = [], descendants
    chain.each do |k|
      subclasses << k unless chain.any? { |c| c > k }
    end
    subclasses
  end
end
```

Back to **running initialiers** by Application. As mentioned above, `run_initializers` is called by `initialize!` [call](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/railties/lib/rails/application.rb#L351) of the Application class:

```
   def initialize!(group=:default) #:nodoc:
      raise "Application has been already initialized." if @initialized
      run_initializers(group, self)
      @initialized = true
      self
    end
```

Which for the Rails app is triggered by `Rails.application.initialize!` call in `environment.rb` file - see [generator source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/environment.rb)

How those initializers got added to the running queue? This happens by adding Devise gem (e.g. by Bundle.require), which loads [lib/devise.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/e01fdba557f0da3c9a528011edee5b4e0989722d/lib/devise.rb) gem root file, and which has following [require](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/e01fdba557f0da3c9a528011edee5b4e0989722d/lib/devise.rb#L491) at the very bottom:

```
require 'devise/rails'
```

As this loads Devise class, it will be discovered by Railties class by looking at subclasses for Engine.

**Back** to Devise devise.url_helpers initializer
If you look at `include_helpers` call, this is what it [does](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise.rb#L433):

```
 def self.include_helpers(scope)
    ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
      include scope::Helpers if defined?(scope::Helpers)
      include scope::UrlHelpers
    end

    ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_view) do
      include scope::UrlHelpers
    end
  end
```

ActiveSupport on_load call is a Rails feature to lazy_load components. [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/39b8b8fdbf6c175a64f07198ff1c950e33c72cd0/activesupport/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb#L26):

> # lazy_load_hooks allows Rails to lazily load a lot of components
>   and thus   # making the app boot faster.

In this case, those include commands for controller will be executed when controller is loaded, but not on server start. Check [this](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/04/understanding-ruby-and-rails-lazy-load-hooks/) or any other articles on the concept.

And this is the place where that lazy block is run - [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/58a221278897a66bf8b9c909389da40ac2c5e534/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb#L263):

```
module ActionController
  # Action Controllers are the core of a web request in \Rails. They are made up of one or more actions that are executed
  # on request and then either it renders a template or redirects to another action. An action is defined as a public method
  # on the controller, which will automatically be made accessible to the web-server through \Rails Routes.
  #
  # By default, only the ApplicationController in a \Rails application inherits from <tt>ActionController::Base</tt>. All other
  # controllers in turn inherit from ApplicationController. This gives you one class to configure things such as
  # request forgery protection and filtering of sensitive request parameters.
 ...
  class Base < Metal
    ...
    ActiveSupport.run_load_hooks(:action_controller, self)
  end
end
```

BTW, your ApplicationController generated by Rails is inherited from ActionController::Base

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks mate :)

Comment: Added some notes on the initializers concept, just as I researched it anyways.

Comment: Updated further. Rails functioning isn't straightforward, by no means.